# How to use file to build a tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

I would like to build a tuple with a file in entry (without a comprehension list).

My file looks like:

```
1 001
2 002
3 003

etc.
```

I'd like to have a tuple like

```
((1, 001),(2, 002) etc.)
```

I tried this :

```
myTuple = set()
with open('./myFile.txt') as fileIN:
    for ligne in fileIN:
        left, right = ligne.split(' ')
```

but here I don't know how to fulfill my tuple..

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Note that `set()` creates a `set` not a tuple. Use `tuple()` or just `()` in order to create a tuple.

Comment: But it seems that " 'tuple' object has no attribute 'add' "

Comment: Ah, right.  Sorry about that. You need to use `list` as tuples are fixed-length and `.append` instead of `.add`.

Comment: A set is bad if you care about the order (as it isn't kept in a set) or if you want to keep duplicates (as sets get rid of those too).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to add to tuple use it:

```
myTuple.add((left, right))
```